# Why won't my HTML Images fade

Tags: javascript, html, fade

I'm trying to create a simple slideshow effect. I have 10 images, and I've created a basic HTML page with 2 buttons to go to the right or left image. On clicking the button, the images change.

Now, I'm trying to add a basic fade functionality to the changing image. But the fade effect isn't getting displayed. When I put alerts, I notice that the fade is taking place, but without the alerts it is too fast to be visible. Also, it is happening on the previous image, instead of the next one.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
        .main {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .centered {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #image {
            border: solid 2px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #number {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function goLeft() {
            var image = document.getElementById("image");
            var pos = document.getElementById("number");
            if(Number(pos.innerHTML)==1) {
                image.src = "Images\\10.jpg"
                pos.innerHTML = 10;
            } else {
                image.src = "Images\\" + (Number(pos.innerHTML)-1).toString() + ".jpg"
                pos.innerHTML = (Number(pos.innerHTML)-1).toString();
            }
            for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
                setTimeout(changeOpacity(image, i), 1000);
            }
        }

        function changeOpacity(image, i) {
            alert(parseFloat(i*4/100).toString());
            image.style.opacity = (parseFloat(i*4/100).toString()).toString();
        }

        function goRight() {
            var image = document.getElementById("image");
            var pos = document.getElementById("number");
            if(Number(pos.innerHTML)==10) {
                image.src = "Images\\1.jpg"
                pos.innerHTML = 1;
            } else {
                image.src = "Images\\" + (Number(pos.innerHTML)+1).toString() + ".jpg"
                pos.innerHTML = (Number(pos.innerHTML)+1).toString();
            }
            for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
                setTimeout(changeOpacity(image, i), 1000);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="centered">
            <img id="image" src="Images\1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="centered">
            <span id="number">1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="centered">
            <button onclick="goLeft()" style="margin-right:50px;">Go Left</button>
            <button onclick="goRight()" style="margin-left:50px;">Go Right</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this block of code that is in your `goLeft` method, and `goRight` method:

```
for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
    setTimeout(changeOpacity(image, i), 1000);
}
```

You are creating 25 timers that, and each timer will execute approximately 1 second later.

Creating animations is best left to the CSS.

In your CSS add:

```
#image {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

And then in your JavaScript, simply: `image.style.opacity = 1.0;`

When the opacity changes, CSS will automatically transition the opacity length at the speed defined in the css, e.g `0.5s`. Feel free to experiment.

I also added a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dya7L8wq/

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood `setTimeout` and the `for` loop.

Norman's answer provides a good solution with CSS, but he doesn't talk too much about why your code is not working. So I'd like to explain.

```
for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
    setTimeout(changeOpacity(image, i), 1000);
}
```

**You assumption is:**

1. invoke `changeOpacity(image, 0)` after 1 second
2. invoke `changeOpacity(image, 1)` 1 second **after step 1**
3. invoke `changeOpacity(image, 2)` 1 second **after step 2**
4. invoke `changeOpacity(image, 3)` 1 second **after step 3**
   ....

And the last step is invoking `changeOpacity(image, 24)` 1 second after previous step.

[image]

**What actually happens is:**

The loop is finished almost immediately!

In each iteration, `setTimeout` queues an **asynchronous** function invocation, and it's done! That says, it will return right away, rather than wait until `changeOpacity` returns.

And then, after about 1 second, `changeOpacity` fires 25 times almost at the same time, because you queued it 25 times in the `for` loop.

[image]

Another problem here is: in `changeOpacity` invocations, passed-in parameter `i` are not `1`, `2`, `3`...., they all have the same value that causes `for` loop to exit (1 second ago) - **`25`**, because JS doesn't have a block scope prior to ES6 (in ES6 we have keyword `let` for it).

---

In a pure JS solution, to ensure the time sequence we'd usually queue next invocation at the end of every step:

```
function changeOpacity() {
    // do something here
    // before the function returns, set up a future invocation
    setTimeout(changeOpacity, 1000)
}
```

Here's an example to print a list of numbers from 1 to 5:

```js
var go = document.getElementById('go')
var op = document.getElementById('output')
var i = 0

function printNum() {
  var p = document.createElement('p')
  p.innerHTML = ++i
  op.appendChild(p)
  
  // next step
  if(i < 5) {
    setTimeout(printNum, 500)
  }
}

go.onclick = printNum
```

```html
<button id="go">GO</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response Leo. It made things clear for me, and I understood what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot for that..

Answer (score 0):

Why use pure JavaScript?
Use **jQuery.**
It has a pretty neat `fadeTo()` function and a useful `fadeIn()` function.

Might wanna use that ;)

Comment: I was looking for a pure JavaScript solution. Actually, I'm trying to learn JavaScript, so didn't really want to use JQuery. But yes, if I was working for a website, that would definitely make more sense.